# Split file by lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, split

i use

```
split --lines=100 file
```

to split file ,and output file has name :

```
xaa ,xab ,xac ,xad ...
```

Is there any way to make output 's name :

```
1,2,3,4 ...

OR

001,002,003,004,...
```

Thanks

Comment: You can specify a filename for the output files after <file>

Comment: If using a Mac like I am, you may find that you need to use the `-l` flag instead of `--lines`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work for the second format you requested (`000`, `001`, `002` etc.):

`split --lines=100 -d -a 3 file ''`

The double single-quotes at the end allow us to override the default prefix (which is x), and replace it with nothing. Try `man split` to see what the other arguments do.

Comment: Thanks much .that was the answer